# Floating table left and right same container

Tags: html, css

I tried to make a footer for a Website im doing for shool. I want to have something like the Impressum on the right and little images for social media on the left. I made it work for the right side but I dont know why the images arent on the right side. I already googled but the things they said didnt worked for me.

[JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1uauqar9/) :

```
<ul>
    <li><a>Irgendwas</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Impressum</a>
    </li>
    <li><a><address>Erstellt von</address></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id="socialmediaicons">
    <li><a><img src="bilder/icons/facebook.svg" width="30" height="30"></img></a>
    </li>
    <li><a><img src="bilder/icons/google+-with-circle.svg" width="30" height="30"></img></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My suggestion is to just place them outside the footer but I need to have them in there.

Comment: Still not answered correctly. JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1uauqar9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the pictures on the left as you mentioned first, add a class to the list items for the socialmedia icons and give it a `display: inline-block`  that should do what you need.  If you want them on the right they are there.

```css
   
.leftFoot {
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<footer id="footer-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a>Irgendwas</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>Impressum</a>
        </li>
        <li><a><address>Erstellt von</address></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="socialmediaicons">
        <li class="leftFoot"><a><img src="bilder/icons/facebook.svg" width="30" height="30"></img></a>
        </li>
        <li class="leftFoot"><a><img src="bilder/icons/google+-with-circle.svg" width="30" height="30"></img></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: I wish it was so easy. I want the pictures on the left and the rest on the right. But even though I said float: left + the display they are on the left side next to the Impressum etc.

Comment: @Alex Knorr Did you remember to add a seperate class to the social media icon <li>? I have it working in your fiddle so that the icons are on the left and the words are on the right.  See it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tlhull1/1uauqar9/2/).

Comment: nvm. Already did this but forgott to change something else back which i edited before. Thx wouldnt noticed it. Its working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the elements in reverse order when floating "right" things :

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1uauqar9/1/)

```
<ul id="socialmediaicons">
    <li><a><img src="bilder/icons/facebook.svg" width="30" height="30"></img></a>
    </li>
    <li><a><img src="bilder/icons/google+-with-circle.svg" width="30" height="30"></img></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><a>Irgendwas</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Impressum</a>
    </li>
    <li><a><address>Erstellt von</address></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nah i want the pictures on the left side of my footer and the rest on the left. Not everything next to eachother

Comment: KK. Well. I already managed to display my whole content (social media links + the rest ) in one line. Thats already working. If you click on the jsfiddle demo link you can see that, but I also want that the socialmediaimages are seperate from the rest => IMG IMG [Space] ... [Space] Irgendwas Impressum Erstellt von. So that the img are aligned on the left side of the box and the rest on the right.